# A friend you could live with?

Tags: riddle

> If you work out with me, you'll quickly tire. 
>  If you talk with my voice, you've lost your desire. 
>  When a joke falls to me, I make nobody laugh. 
>  When I annotate a letter, I take away half.

Who or what am I?

In your answer, please explain each line and the title.

Comment: Is that meant to be 'lost' instead of 'lot'?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are

> flat.

If you work out with me, you'll quickly tire.

> If you work flat out, you work as fast as possible.

If you talk with my voice, you've lost your desire.

> A flat voice is monotonous and lacks emotion.

When a joke falls to me, I make nobody laugh.

> A joke that falls flat isn't funny.

When I annotate a letter, I take away half.

> The letters are musical notes, which will be pitched half a note lower when annotated with the flat sign, ♭.

And of course, a friend you could live with is a

> flat mate

Comment: Yes, great! There was a semi-intentional use of the word tire (tyre) in the first clue but there is a better fit. Think about an idiom for doing something as fast or as hard as possible.

Comment: @ M Oehm Maybe for the first clue you could add - If you work flat out then you would tire - to your answer

Comment: @Tom: Thanks. I've just edited my answer. While searching the web for "work out flat" turned up many ab exercises, adding "expression" to the search term I've found what I wanted. (Didn't know that expression.)

Comment: @hexomino - This is an example of where using the US spelling is the better choice.  If you spelled it the UK-way, it would remove that ambiguity, but to the riddle's detriment.  (Although of course the answer itself is a British-ism, but most Americans would at least know what it means.)

Comment: I was thinking exercising on a bike with a flat tire